# Como enviar dados de um formulário gerado pelo Ionic Framework para um arquivo PHP e retornar um JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, json, ionic

Venho seguindo a documentação do [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com) e vendo tutoriais na internet, mas não há detalhe de comunicação com o servidor. Gostaria de enviar dados de formulários e receber informações via JSON. Poderiam postar um exemplo simples de como enviar dados para o script PHP? Por exemplo: nome, e-mail e telefone. Acho que isso vai ajudar a todos que estão ingressando no uso do framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia estar utilizando $http do próprio angular para enviar esses dados, e no php retorna o json.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

link para a documentação do $http, ali tem alguns exemplos de utilização

Comment: Obrigado. Acredito que isso me sirva. Infelizmente o pessoal negativou a pergunta. Sinceramente não entendo esses usuários.